# Possibility of not calling Activity.onResume()

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

My app does a lot of setting up in onCreate and then in onResume.

Is it possible that if a device rotation occurs while onCreate is being performed then onResume won't be called?

I'm asking because I receive many crash logs happening in onPause(). The crashes occur, because in onResume() I ALWAYS register some listeners and in onPause they are ALWAYS unregistered. Exception is thrown when a listener that hasn't been registered is unregistered.

So: is it possible that onResume() is not called at all before onPause()?

Comment: Whenever onCreate call onResume must called, and after onPause when you again come to activity onResume has to be called that is in the nature of activity life cycle, you can keep a flag in on onPause and skip code in onResume if you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
 is it possible that onResume() is not called at all before onPause()?
```

No. Never.

---

`onResume()` Called just before the activity starts interacting with the user. At this point the activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.
***Always followed by `onPause()`***. So if `onPause()` of an Activity is being called means `onResume()` must called.

---

Read  [***A summary of the activity lifecycle's callback methods***](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) for more details.

Comment: Read the OP's question again - in particular... "if a device rotation occurs *while onCreate is being performed*". I'm not saying my answer is correct but it seems possible that the life-cycle will be interrupted and possible that `onStart` and `onResume` may be skipped. We'd have to dig in to the AOSP code files to get a definitive answer though.

Comment: @Squonk hey, you are correct. I read carefully his question. And yes this is a good idea to look into AOSP code. Will update if found suspect :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that if a device rotation occurs while onCreate is being performed then onResume won't be called?

Yes possibly, although it seems highly unlikely. Even if you are doing a lot of stuff in `onCreate` in relative terms you should never be doing so much that it takes several seconds. In other words, for a user to start your `Activity` and then rotate the device is going to take some finite 'human reaction' time.

If you believe this is happening then...

1. Reduce the amount of stuff going on in `onCreate`
2. NEVER assume that your listeners are registered - check first. Example, when you register a listener set a `boolean` and only unregister if it's true and set the `boolean` to false...

Psuedo code:

```
// To register
if (!isListenerRegistered) {
    register(...);
    isListenerRegistered = true;
}

// To unregister
if (isListenerRegistered) {
    unregister(...);
    isListenerRegistered = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

the sequence is always onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), then the user sees the activity in the foreground(totally visible).  Once another activity starts, this one goes to onPause(), then onStop().

When the device is rotated the activity gets reloaded, so it goes through the destruction steps depending on when the rotation occured.  After onDestroy() is called, the creation starts again with onCreate().  Add log messages in your callbacks to see this:

```
Log.d("DEBUG", "In Activity A's onCreate()");
```

You can filter your logcat via the log tag, in this case "DEBUG" and see the lifecycle for yourself.  Or just step through with the debugger.

Comment: Read the OP's question again - in particular... "if a device rotation occurs *while onCreate is being performed*". I'm not saying my answer is correct but it seems possible that the life-cycle will be interrupted and possible that `onStart` and `onResume` may be skipped. We'd have to dig in to the AOSP code files to get a definitive answer though.